# How to get cells and return in html link

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql, django

I have a table created by a sql query and have made each cell clickable. I want to redirect the cell to a link containing that is as follow : `/protein/proteinseq/table[row][2nd col]/ table[row][3rdcol]/table[row][5th col]/`

I have no idea how to do this, I can make the link have the current cell that was clicked on but I need the specifics specific columns from the row that was clicked. This is my code for the table so far:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>

        <title>{% block title %} Protein Table {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block pagecontent %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/tablecss.css' %}"/>

<h1>
    Showing results for group id : {{group_id}} and assembly id : {{assembly_id}}
</h1>



<table>

    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>peptide_id</th>
        <th>protein_id</th>
        <th>group_id</th>
        <th>search_id</th>
        <th>peptide_parsimony</th>
    </tr>


{% for elem in elem_list %}

    <tr>

    {% for sub_elem in elem %}

        <td onclick="location.href='/protein/proteinseq/{{ elem.peptide_id }}/{{ elem.protein_id }}/{{ elem.search_id }}/'">{{ sub_elem }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the cell the url should return

```
/protein/proteinseq/peptide_id/protein_id/search_id/
```

Instead it just returns

```
/protein/proteinseq////
```

If possible, could you give me an example because I am new to html and have not used javascript or other languages very much. Thanks :)

Comment: Does your query return the values needed for the link? If so, you just need to put those values in the link in your *td onclick* attribute.In other words, where the ```{{sub_elem}}``` is located.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I did my query in views.py. Also, the link would be different for each row so I could not give any more data.

Comment: Right, if your query returns the information, it would be specific to each row and/or cell. I'm asking if your query returns the values for ```peptide_id```, ```protein_id``` and ```search_id```.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yes I can my query returns those and outputs them into the table. The elem_list is a list with all my query data and the two for loops output them into a table

Comment: @SloanThrasher My query does return those values in a list

Comment: So just replace ``{{sub_elem}}``` with those variable names. IOW, instead of ``{{sub_elem}}```, put ```//proteintable/{{peptide_id}}/{{protein_id}}/{{search_id}}``

Comment: @SloanThrasher The three id are different for each row though so how could I do a return them for each row. I am doing a query and returning a whole table, so I am basically doing a select *. Then formatting that list into a table. I can get the id's for a specific row but that would not help.

Comment: At least give what I suggested a try.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I did but I don't what to do for the html context? What row should I do the query on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195823/discussion-between-agent-lu-and-sloan-thrasher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>peptide_id</th>
        <th>protein_id</th>
        <th>group_id</th>
        <th>search_id</th>
        <th>peptide_parsimony</th>
    </tr>


{% for elem in elem_list %}

    <tr>

    {% for sub_elem in elem %}



        <td onclick="location.href='/proteintable/{{ elem['peptide_id'] }}/{{ elem['protein_id'] }}/{{ elem['search_id'] }}/'">{{ sub_elem }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Or try:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>peptide_id</th>
        <th>protein_id</th>
        <th>group_id</th>
        <th>search_id</th>
        <th>peptide_parsimony</th>
    </tr>


{% for elem in elem_list %}

    <tr>

    {% for sub_elem in elem %}



        <td onclick="location.href='/proteintable/{{ elem.1 }}/{{ elem.2 }}/{{ elem.4 }}/'">{{ sub_elem }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: To clarify the elem is the row of the table and the numbers are the column for each row. This will send you to a link based on the row you click on